# Alarm clock needs repairing by you

Tags: gerunds

A new, quite actually exciting, question has occurred in my mind.

I know that when we use *need* with gerunds, the meaning is passive, for example:

• The cat needs feeding.

So, can we use those need-gerunds with prepositions?

Examples:

1. The alarm clock lying on my table needs repairing by you, Dad.

Equals: The alarm clock lying on my table needs to be repaired by you, Dad.

2. Some money needs giving to me, Detective Watson.

Equals: Some money needs to be given to me, Detective Watson.

3. George's safes need stealing from his cellar.

Equals: George's safes need to be stolen from his cellar.

Comment: My Yorkshire girlfriend used to say 'your hair wants cutting'. I suspect it's non-standard to use a gerund in that way.